# How to remove all words from TreeSet ignore care

Tags: java, collections

I created two sets:

```
   public static Set<String> COMMON_ENGLISH_WORDS = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
   public static Set<String> NON_ENGLISH_WORDS = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

I kept all my common english words arround 58000 and non english word arround 1700 in two files seperately. And I am loading from file and asigning to above two variables. That assigment is happening properly that I check by debug.

```
    public static void finalNonEnglishWords(){
        ToolsConstants.COMMON_ENGLISH_WORDS = CSVFileUtil.readCSVToTreeSet(ToolsConstants.COMMON_ENGLISH_WORDS_FILE);
        ToolsConstants.NON_ENGLISH_WORDS = CSVFileUtil.readCSVToTreeSet(ToolsConstants.NON_ENGLISH_WORDS_FILE);
        System.out.println(ToolsConstants.NON_ENGLISH_WORDS.size());
        ToolsConstants.NON_ENGLISH_WORDS.removeAll(ToolsConstants.COMMON_ENGLISH_WORDS);
        System.out.println(ToolsConstants.NON_ENGLISH_WORDS.size());
}
```

But it not removing.
I am seeing same number in output.
But I saw both files, there are some common words.

I did the same sample with just 7 elements but it working perfectly. And fallowed the same way only different is number of elements in collection.

```
public static void removeAllDemo(){
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList("BOB", "Joe", "john", "MARK","MARk", "dave", "Bill")
        );

        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("JOE", "MARK", "DAVE", "Ravi");

// Add all values of list1 in a case insensitive collection
        Set<String> set1 = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        set1.addAll(list1);
// Add all values of list2 in a case insensitive collection
        Set<String> set2 = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        set2.addAll(list2);
// Remove all common Strings ignoring case
        System.out.println(set1);
        set1.removeAll(set2);
        System.out.println(set1);
// Keep in list1 only the remaining Strings ignoring case
        list1.retainAll(set1);

    }
```

Comment: Maybe the non english words have a different character e.g. e but with a hat. Which words are still the same? 
Can you print those words to Base64 and compare between english words and non english words?

Comment: Please share some more details please.

Comment: *"But it not removing"* - at which stage you're having an issue, with `removeAll()`? Can provide an example when a target string is being omitted by `removeAll()` ?

Comment: In NON_ENGLISH_WORDS set contains 'About', 'Accept'..... . But in COMMON_ENGLISH_WORD contains all small lettet words only. ie. 'about', 'accept'.....

Comment: The initializer `new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` is irrelevant if you *replace* the object completely like with `COMMON_ENGLISH_WORDS = CSVFileUtil.readCSVToTreeSet(…)` Then, `COMMON_ENGLISH_WORDS` will be whatever `readCSVToTreeSet` returned, case sensitive or case insensitive or having an entirely different comparator, who knows.

Comment: @Holger is right. Could you show us the content of `CSVFileUtil.readCSVToTreeSet`? I bet the famous TreeSet/removeAll bug is involved.

Answer (score 0):

So generally you should apply the same approach as that implemented in the demo method:

- appropriate empty sets with the case-insensitive order are already created
- use `addAll` to populate the sets
- remove duplicates from the set of non-English words

```java
public static void finalNonEnglishWords() {
    ToolsConstants.COMMON_ENGLISH_WORDS.addAll( 
        CSVFileUtil.readCSVToTreeSet(ToolsConstants.COMMON_ENGLISH_WORDS_FILE)
    );
    ToolsConstants.NON_ENGLISH_WORDS.addAll( 
        CSVFileUtil.readCSVToTreeSet(ToolsConstants.NON_ENGLISH_WORDS_FILE)
    );
    System.out.println(ToolsConstants.NON_ENGLISH_WORDS.size());
 
    ToolsConstants.NON_ENGLISH_WORDS.removeAll(
        ToolsConstants.COMMON_ENGLISH_WORDS
    );
    System.out.println(ToolsConstants.NON_ENGLISH_WORDS.size());
}
```